# Htmlentities OR htmlspecialchars OR stripslashes?

Tags: php, xss

I would like to prevent XSS attack on my website using PHP.

I know that there are 3 functions which could basically prevent this attack, but I'm not sure which one should I use. I have seen other questions about this before, but I didn't get a CLEAR answer for this question.

Which one should I use, which one is the best on your opinion and why?

Comment: What questions have you seen, and how were the answers not clear?

Comment: Neither. there are better options. [**htmlpurifier**](http://www.htmlpurifier.org)

Comment: @itachi: For the record, I consider that a very inferior option.

Comment: Someone says that I should use HTMLentities, someone told me to use HTMLspecialchars, someone tells to use stripslashes, I don't really know which one is the best at the moment, to use.

Comment: @Exorcist: So you ask this question. And then someone else will tell you to do X (actually, itachi *already did that*). How did that improve the situation? Is having heard N+1 opinions better than having heard N?

Comment: Becuase of this question I have asked in my first post: "Which one should I use, which one is the best on your opinion and why?"

Comment: @Jon probably it is if compared to another Y library. but comparing to `Htmlentities OR htmlspecialchars OR stripslashes`, it certainly is better.

Comment: Hey guys, that's a valid question and a serious topic. And there are a lot of Myths and Rumors about "preventing attacks" around there so get the questioner helped and don't blame each other on breadcrumbs.

Comment: I don't have much more to add apart from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1996122/50079) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php). I have no idea how those answers can be considered unclear.

Answer (score 2):

**htmlspecialchars** or **htmlentities** will protect if outputting untrusted data between tags, but will not protect if outputting is in JavaScript event handler.

The way to use this function is something like this:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Take a look at the OWASP XSS prevention cheat sheet...

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

http://code.google.com/edu/security/index.html#videos

Answer (score 0):

None of them can *prevent* an attack. 
You may only limit the damage!

But using all or just one is not the question, it's about application design and whether its possible to modify requests in a way that the result is going down to the database level.

See [this](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies) - probably this will give you an idea on complexity of XSS attacks.

Comment: This is simply not true.

Comment: If you're going to sanitize the request values (POST/GET) in order to not have malicious data in it, you're already _AFTER_ an attack and thus do not have prevented it but just dealing with the attack itself.

Comment: You are not going to *sanitize* anything, but instead properly *escape* the input before displaying it. In any case, using your definition of "prevent" there is no attack in the world that can be "prevented". I 'm not sure how that definition is useful.

Comment: But that was the question: _I would like to prevent XSS attack on my website using PHP._ And I think we both mean the same: an attack can not be prevented.

Comment: Only with your definition of "prevent" -- not with mine. But let's drop the subject here because it has moved past technology and gotten into philosophy.